# How to ship fonts with react native npm package and auto link

Tags: react-native, npm

I am creating react-native component library I am able to consume it in another app but how about fonts how can I auto-link fonts from a package?

Using react-native-builder-bob for packaging.

Comment: Did you found a solution for that? I was working with expo-font to load async and it works but when I convert to nom package with Bob, it is failing

Comment: No solution for auto-link but partial solution i'll update that in answers it's quite big please check that @AgustinHerrera

Answer (score 0):

There is partial solution i did

S1: Shipping `src` folder `package.json` module config looks like this:

```
...
"main": "lib/module/index.js",
"module": "lib/module/index.js",
"react-native": "src/index.tsx",
"types": "lib/typescript/src/index.d.ts",
...
```

*keeping assets inside `src` folder folder structure looks like*

```
src
  |--assets
  |--components
  |--index
```

S2: Then for setup readme i've added this package config step

Link assets:

````
1. Create `react-native.config.js` and add following

    ```bash
    module.exports = {
        project: {
            ios: {},
            android: {},
        },
        assets: ["node_modules/@<YOUR PKG SCOPE>/<PKG NAME>/src/assets/"]
    }
    ```

    or run

    ```bash
    touch react-native.config.js && echo "module.exports = {
        project: {
            ios: {},
            android: {},
        },
        assets: ["node_modules/@<YOUR PKG SCOPE>/<PKG NAME>/src/assets/"]
    };" > react-native.config.js
    ```

2. link assets - `yarn react-native link`
````